# Learning F# and trying to figure out syntax

Tags: compiler-errors, f#

I'm new to F# if someone can explain to me this error please

### [4; 5; 2; 7] :: 3;;

stdin(4,17): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
'int list list'
but here has type
'int'

Answer (score 5):

The error message is a little confusing, but what the compiler thinks you are trying to do is `cons` a list of `int`s onto an integer, which isn't possible.

In F#, `::` is used to add an element on the left to a list on the right. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/lists#operators-for-working-with-lists) for more details. Lists are singly-linked in F#, meaning that it's trivial to add to the *front*, but not as easy to add to the *end*.

To use `::` properly, you should invert your expression: `3 :: [4;5;6;7]`. This will produce `[3;4;5;6;7]`.

Answer (score 1):

- `stdin(4,17):` The error code is on line 4, char 17 (you are only reporting the problematic line which presumably is line 4 in your code.)
- char 17 points to the `3` - this is the start of the 'expression' the compiler is complaining about
- *that* expression is inferred to be type `int` (and this is correct)
- the *preceeding* expression is that of an `int list` (`[4; 5; 2; 7]`) being the *item* to cons (`::`) - prepend to the front -  onto a list of the item type - so the compiler infers and expects a list of `int list` - that is `int list list` i.e. something like this would work:
  `[4; 5; 2; 7] :: [[3 ]]` which would produce `[[4; 5; 2; 7];[3 ]]`
- so it expects an `int list list` type after the cons `::` but sees an `int` hence the error message.
- guessing you might be coming from a C# background you probably want to `3 :: [4; 5; 2; 7]` which would produce `[ 3 ; 4; 5; 2; 7]`. Now the item type is `int` and the list of item type is `int list` and the compiler is happy.